# Bookmarklet for random number input between specific ranges

Tags: javascript, math, random, bookmarklet

I am trying to create javascript bookmarklet that it can fill boxes with numbers, range between 55-99 on any random web site.

I wrote this but it doesn't work as expected

```
var min = 55;
var max = 99;

Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;,
```

Note: If there is any violation against topic policy please forgive me.

Comment: _""It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question."_

Comment: The title should give a summary of the problem. Right now it doesn't tell us anything about the actual problem.

Comment: _"Please help me ASAP."_ - That's not how SO works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You meant something like this?

```js
(function() {
const min = 55, max = 99, ran = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
[...document.querySelectorAll("[type=number]")].forEach(fld => fld.value=ran());
})()
```

```html
<input type="number"><input type="number"><input type="number"><input type="number"><input type="number"><input type="number"><input type="number">
```

Comment: Yes exactly  dear friend but I can't add it as bookmarklet. It gives error. By the way thank you for being so kind to me. I violated tons of rules while opening this topic.

Comment: What error. You of course need to change the queryselector to match your specific sites' field types/names

Comment: thanks man I handled it thanks to you. Just changed it from number to text